# How to add the extra data field into the database in ajax table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

[image: This is the ajax table i have been working with]

```
    function save($data){
    if(count($data)){
        $values = implode("','", array_values($data));
        mysql_query("insert into info (".implode(",",array_keys($data)).") values ('".$values."')");

        if(mysql_insert_id()) return mysql_insert_id();
        return 0;
    }
    else return 0;  
  }
```

Above is the code to insert the values into database... i want to add an extra field those value is to be sent by session variable to the database to store which holds the id of the view button that is pressed. I have the problem with implode function...is there any other way to do it..please help..the rows are generated dynamically..

Answer (score 0):

Simply add your extra field pre or post of array implode in the statement this can work.

```
mysql_query("insert into info ('IDHere',".implode(",",array_keys($data)).") values ('IDValueHere',".$values."')");
```